# Toad for Oracle Grid is read-only

Tags: toad

Version : Toad for Oracle 13.0  (Trial)

The data grid is read-only and I can't find a way to change it.

- Options\Data Grids\Data  checkbox "Use read-only queries" is UNCHECKED
- The Context Menu has no option to change read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option you reference controls grids that Toad populates automatically like those on the Schema Browser, Data tab.

If you are running your own queries in the Editor you need to run editable statements. These include ROWID.

Example...

```
select rowid, t.* from my_table t;
```

Similarly you can run an edit statement and Toad will insert ROWID automatically.

Example...

```
edit my_table;
```

If you are running your SQL as a script (F5) then grids are always read-only.